# Php loop mysql result by year from date field

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I'm getting data from the database and want to present the data by year.
Like this:

**2013**

Event A

Event B

**2012**

Event X

Event Y
Etc.

I've got this mysql query and PHP code which presents all the data in one list:

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table a
INNER JOIN posts b
ON a.event_id = b.ID
WHERE a.user_id = 14
ORDER BY a.event_date DESC
```

PHP:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    if ($results) {
        echo '<h3>Title</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $event_id = $row->event_id;
            $rawDate = $row->event_date;
            $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($rawDate));

            echo '<li>' . $newDate . ': <a href="' . tribe_get_event_link($row->event_id) . '" target="_blank">' . $row->post_title . '</a> (' . $row->points . ' PE)</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

So I like to get this data by year from the field event_date or $newDate which is a date field in Y-m-d H:i:s format, but I can't get this done. I guess I need an extra foreach, but how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, this doesn't need an extra loop. You want to implement what's referred to as a _control break_. You simply compare the year of the current record with that of the previous one, and depending on whether they are the same or different, you react accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe commented, save the previous value and compare with the current value inside your loop:

```php
    if ($results) {
        $pre = '';                                      // previous year
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $current = date("Y", strtotime($row->event_date));
            if ($current != $pre) {
                echo empty($pre) ? '' : '</ul>';       // close list, but not on 1st run
                echo '<h3>'.$current.'</h3>';          // output if year changed
                echo '<ul>';
                $pre = $current;                       // set new previous year
            }


            $event_id = $row->event_id;
            $rawDate = $row->event_date;
            $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($rawDate));

            echo '<li>' . $newDate . ': <a href="' . tribe_get_event_link($row->event_id) . '" target="_blank">' . $row->post_title . '</a> (' . $row->points . ' PE)</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';                                 // final list close
    }
```

Comment: Only problem is that the first <li> following the <h3> and <li> tags is also closed with a </ul>-tag and the complete list does not have a closing </ul>-tag. I think this is because $pre is set after the 2nd if $current != $pre statement. At that point this is true, because at that point $pre is still '' (empty).

Comment: Edit 2: close lists only after the year changed and add a final list close.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to query:

```
$query = "SELECT *,YEAR(event_date) as title FROM table a INNER JOIN posts b ON a.event_id = b.ID WHERE a.user_id = 14 ORDER BY a.event_date DESC";
```

Update to loop:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$events=array();
foreach($results as $key=>$value){
   $events[$value['title']][]=$value;
}
```

Display:

```
if ($events) {
        foreach ($events as $title=>$list) {
           echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
           echo '<ul>';
           foreach($list as $row){
              //your-existing-code-here...
           }
           echo '</ul>';
        }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a critical error on the array part near []=$value. I will check it a bit more.

Comment: @Jason Please check attached screenshot for working code sample.

https://www.yogile.com/y6o4ujtwa83#21t